# Tibco ActiveMatrix BusinessWorks JMS Queue Sender with Message Type Object

Tags: jms, tibco, businessworks

I am new to Tibco, ActiveMatrix BusinessWorks and Tibco Designer.

I followed the Tutorial of Jazon Samillano regarding [sending and receiving JMS Message](http://www.xmarter.com/tibco-training-center/tibco-businessworks-developer-series/tibco-designer-developer-tutorial-send-and-receive-jms-messages.php)s. In this tutorial he sends a Text within the JMS Body to the Queue.

What I am now trying is to send a Java-Object via another Java-Application to the Queue and read the Java-Object within Tibco Designer with the Palette-Element JMS Queue Receiver. After that I want to process the data and then send a JMS Message to another Queue with the same Object (with some slight manipulations) via a JMS Queue Sender.

In the configuration of the JMS Queue Receiver and of the JMS Queue Sender there is a Dropdown List where I can chose the Message Type "Object". But what do I have to do then. I think I need to make a mapping between the JMS Body to a variable (= the reprasentation of the Java Object in Tibco Designer) to process the data. But how can I do this?

Does anyone knows a good tutorial or can anyone explain how I can do this?

I would really really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you have received is serialized java objects via JMS. You can use the Java Palettes Activity to deserialize it and do whatever you want to do with that object. If your serialized object not from standard Java class (e.g. String) then you need to have the java class or jar in the class path of designer.